# What is the problem in this program?

Tags: functions, core-language

The output is showing running only.

```
For[m = 0, m < 0.05, m++,
  For[a = 5, a < 20, a + 1,
    a1 = a*(a/2);
    x[m] = a1
    ];
  ];
```

Comment: Please explain in plain language what you are trying to do. Your program does not stop because the value of `a` is never changed, so it never exceeds 20.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but it seems that the outer `For` evaluates its $body$ once; also, in the inner `For`, the 3rd argument should probably be written as`a++`; finally, if `x`is supposed to be a list, I think it should have been assigned to a list, before starting to manipulate it, like in `a[m]=a1` and it should have been `a[[m]]=a1` with `m`an integer.

Comment: Looks to me like the entire nested loop boils down to one simple assignment: `x[0] = a (a/2) /. a -> 19`.

Answer (score 2):

Change `a+1`to `a++`

```
For[m = 0, m < 0.05, m++, For[a = 5, a < 20, a++, a1 = a*(a/2);x[m] = a1]]
x[0]
(*361/2*)
```